# why xcode show me a error:"Returning block that lives on the local stack"?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

[image: code]

I can't understand why xcode show me that error in ARC.
In ARC, why not the block copy itself automatically?

Comment: Are you sure this is Objective-C? It just looks like plain C to me. There is no ARC in C.

Answer (score 0):

A block lives in a scope. It is only valid as long as that scope is still active, or if it is copied. Once copied, the copy remains valid forever Copying a block is not the same as retaining it, that's why Xcode gives you an error instead of ARC doing it for you. "Why doesn't the block copy itself" is a totally irrelevant question - it doesn't, and that's that. You have to copy it yourself.

That's why you make block properties "copy". Passing blocks to gcd is no problem, because gcd will copy the block if needed.

Comment: But starting with ARC, clang promised to automatically copy (not retain) blocks that leave the local scope. I cannot find that in the documentation right now, but I'm pretty sure.